# Angular4 -Building dynamic forms from RestAPI Jsondata for fields

Tags: angular, observable, dynamic-forms

I am building a form builder application using following the Tutorial https://toddmotto.com/angular-dynamic-components-forms

I was able to build using that example & add it to my project. The data for the form comes from httpClient. Once I brought in the observable, then the data passing to the child components got out of sync.

I tried to pass the observable to the child similar to the template below

```
<div>
<dynamic-form
[fieldCfg]="fieldConfig|async"
#form="dynamicForm"
(submit)="submit($event)">
</dynamic-form>
{{ form.valid }}
{{ form.value | json }}
</div>
```

where `fieldConfig` is an observable. When I pass it to my child component & subscribe it on `ngOnChanges`, I get the error cannot subscribe to `this.fieldConfig`. I am relatively new to angular, and I would like to know the best approach to tackle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `async` pipe it automatically subscribes for you. So now in the field `fieldCfg` you don't have an `Observable<T>` but the `T` so it's the result of the `Observable`

Comment: Hi SebOlens, so is it better to have fieldcfg as an array itself?  or how do I set the fieldcfg as an Observable? What is the recommended approach? Thanks so much!

Comment: it's always better to use a pipe cause they are optimized for angular's change detection system and just convenient . So in this case it's better if you stick to the pipe.  if the type of `fieldConfig` is `Observable<something>` where **something** is the type your **observable returns** after subscribing to it then `fieldCfg' in your dynamic-form component should be of type **something**. You're getting the subscribe error because in your child the fieldCfg is no longer an observable. It is its materialized value

Comment: Thanks SebOlens, I was able to use the async pipe from parent & get the results directly to the array of FieldConfig type that I was looking for. Appreciate your quick response and explaining clearly what happens in async for an observable.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding :) Don't forget to upvote the answer

Comment: hi SebOlens, tried to upvote the answer but doesnt let me , looks like I have less than 15 reputations!

Comment: Hi SebOlens, Have another question. In my rest api, I have the validations required for the form array also coming through JSON. My json data is like   {
  "type": "input",
  "label": "Invoice Number",
  "name": "invoice_number",
  "placeholder": "Invoice Number goes here",
  "value" : "123456",
  "validation": "[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]"
  },

Comment: The problem I have is when I attach it to the form array, it expects validators.required without the double quotes. What is the best way to do this? All my data/properties of the form is coming from another rest api. Thanks!

Comment: That's interesting and also it's a kind of odd structure. I would use regex with two groups to get what's after the dot and what's in the parenthesis and then I'd assing it as `Validators[firstgroup](secondgroup)` to the form control. Sorry for such a general answer but a full answer requires some work to be done